# Wireless connection is slow and unreliable with Ubuntu 16.04 and Atheros QCA9377 device

Tags: 16.04, wireless

So I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my old dell inspirion laptop its in dual boot with window 10. Initially I could not get network manager to work in ubuntu. so connect my ethernet and did sudo apt update which kind of fixed my network manager.

Now while using Wifi I am having issue with my internet connection. intermittent loss of conection (loss of ssh connection, self duplication of connections when I try to edit connection from network manager >> edit connection >> network connection window).

My all other devices work fine on my router so I know router is not an issue. sudo apt update takes too long to start update. firefox takes to long to connect to websites. even ssh over vpn some times get stuck due to connection.

not sure what is wrong with my network configuration.

```
ifconfig


enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:40:bb:36:4d:cf  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:48675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:28227020 (28.2 MB)  TX bytes:28227020 (28.2 MB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a8:6b:ad:3c:7a:07  
          inet addr:192.168.1.21  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4c2e:fb27:b13c:b82d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:93584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:90110775 (90.1 MB)  TX bytes:10132544 (10.1 MB)
```

EDIT 1:
Output of cmd `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Are you using a USB or a PCI wireless device?

Comment: Not a usb device. I am using dell laptop has wireless card inbuilt.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: All looks well. So what is wrong? You are connected, you got an IP...

Comment: when I so ```network-test``` I get following error ```ERR: System can access the Internet, but the received files are modified somehow (file had md5 '62962daa1b19bbcc2db10b7bfd531ea6', expected ' 5cd5515e6d2f9026fef667cdef4cda42'
ERR: Cannot access IP address service at Internet host http://queryip.net/ip/```

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. Can you access internet sites? What is `network-test`?

Comment: network test http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/network-test.1.html

Comment: Does everything else work OK?

Comment: I can access internet sites but connection is not stable it takes too long but on other devices its very fast

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what is the problem. Now it is very unclear. Also why did you install 16.04 to a new hardware?

Comment: edited the Question hope now it is understandable

Comment: Your question is totally unrelated to Network Manager. Why not say that your wireless connection is slow and unreliable?

Comment: That is what I am saying. the internet work good in windows and not in ubuntu other devices but my configuration might be wrong in ubuntu

Comment: please read the question again. I have made changes

Comment: I have the same exact issue with the same exact errors! No idea what's going on though! BTW, I also on a DELL laptop + Ubuntu 16.04!